# How to unzip and rename a specific folder inside zip file, using CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, zip

I have a zip file located in my Documents folder, called "Test.zip"

I would like to do the following:
Using CMD (Not PowerShell, nor VBS Script) extract one folder inside this file "Test.zip" called "Folder_test" and extract it with the name Folder_renamed .

I know how to do this on Linux using TAR, but i have no idea how to do it using Windows.
Can someone please help?

Recap: Enter Test.zip file, get Folder_test only and extract it but with the name Folder_renamed.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not use `tar.exe` that comes with Windows?

Comment: It does not come with older versions of Windows, sadly...

Comment: `older versions of windows` .. you might mention that in your question. :) .. For real zip file, I think you are not going to find what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Comment: If you can't use tar or powershell you would have to use a third party solution that doesn't ship with windows like winrar or 7zip

Comment: @RicardoBohner I solved this using the third party solution 7zip. It worked like a charm, if you want you can go ahead and answer it below and i'll mark as a solution